# IEEEtran-compsoc class messes up "description"

Tags: ieeetran, description

I'm using the template

```
%% bare_jrnl_compsoc.tex
%% V1.3
%% 2007/01/11
%% by Michael Shell
%% See:
%% http://www.michaelshell.org/
%% for current contact information.
```

which can be downloaded from here:
http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html for my paper. It works fine, except for one thing: I would like to use the `description`environment, but the result is quite a mess: 
[image: sexample of too long description names] 
The underlinings are not a problem; they will be erased later. However, it seems that the description environment has a problem if the word after `\item[THIS WORD]`is too long.

Is there any easy fix for this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a link to this template? Does the template come with some reproducible content?

Comment: @Werner, I added the link to the template to my post. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Ah, I think I just found an answer to my question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55877/how-can-i-have-a-smaller-indentation-in-description-with-ieeetran?rq=1 

Should I delete this one then?